# Using the app Background Music gives only distorted audio now

Tags: audio, apple-silicon

I have a M1 pro, for which I downloaded [Background Music](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic). First it worked perfectly but now it only generates distorted noice, in which you can faintly recognise what should have been played. There are more people who report issues with MS Teams, however I'm not running Teams.

How can I find the source of this problem (and resolve the distortion)?

Comment: What is the output device ? Do you have the problem if you disable Background Music

Comment: @mmmmmm The output device is technically background music. It does not matter if I choose the built in speakers, headset or whatever as the real output device within background music, it all ends up distorted. When background music is not running as the middle man, the audio normal.

Comment: The source of the distortion is thus in Background Music - I think best to ask in their GitHub

Comment: @mmmmmm Is there a way to give the developer more information?

Comment: Ask themn - they are the ones who know what information they need